# Is there a way I can get PHP 1.0, the CGI old version?

Tags: php, cgi

I seems to be unable to find PHP 1.0, that, as stated by wikipedia, was just a bunch of CGI functions to handle common web-related things.
Is there a way I can download it or see how was done? Why doesn't PHP mention it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linked from the php site (left hand sidebar):

http://museum.php.net/

(why? Maybe because they're a little bit embarrassed :-) )